# Google Chrome tab ID changes in tab's lifetime

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm implementing a Google Chrome extensions that handles tabs. This includes that I fetch the `onCreated`, `onUpdated` and `onActivated`. Each time, I use the `tabId` in my logic, initially stored in an array during the handling of `onCreated` events. In principle, everything works fine.

However, I noticed a glitch. Occasionally, the ID of an already existing tab changes. Thus, a tab has then an ID that is not in my array, which naturally results in errors. I can reproduce this issue in the following use case:

- open 2 or more tabs with different URLs
- load in one tab T a URL that is already loaded in another tab

In this case, two things happen: Firstly, instead of the `onUpdated` event, the `onActivated` event for T fires. And secondly, T has now a new ID, typically incremented by 2.

This seems to me far from intuitive. I would even call it a bug. Has anybody an idea what's going here?

Any hints are much appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's likely caused by [prerendering](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender). This can be detected by listening to the [`chrome.webNavigation.onTabReplaced`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onTabReplaced) or [`chrome.tabs.onReplaced`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onReplaced) event. Also refer to the the [webNavigation event order](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/#event-order) section for more details.

Comment: Woah, that was fast! And you're right, it is the prerendering. If I start Chrome with `google-chrome  --prerender-from-omnibox=disabled` everything works. And the `chrome.webNavigation.onTabReplaced` event is also fired. I hope I can tweak it enough to make it fir my needs. Anyway, thanks a lot!